Azure Durable Function - Non-US Symbols
Using Powershell 7.2 and Azure Durable Function.
I am looking for some assistance regarding an issue I have been facing and for the love of all that is good, I can't seem to resolve it.
I have an Azure Durable Function with a HTTP trigger and orchestration.
I am sending JSON Body to the HTTP trigger, which include a British Pound Symbol (£).
When I output $Request.Body - I can see the pound symbol decoded correctly in the HTTP Trigger output, either output to console or push output binding.
However, the issue appears as soon as I pass the $Request.Body , to the durable function as an INPUT
and then read the $Context in the orchestrator, I receive � instead of £.
Have tried several suggestions to force UTF-8
Firstly in the HTTP Trigger, before the data is passed to the orchestration
Secondly, using Context when the data is received by the orchestration.
Something on the lines of :
$requestBodyBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Request.Body.ToString()) $requestContent = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($requestBodyBytes)
I have tried sending the data as JSON but also as text, with just the British Pound symbol.
When using the above mentioned method, the symbol becomes a ? instead of the diamond symbol � . That is the only difference I spotted.
The issue just appears that when azure function passes the data from the HTTP Trigger, to the orchestration, that is when the encoding issue seems to occur.
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{ symbol = ($Request.Body).symbol } $obj.symbol
Return : [2024-06-10T12:12:36.414Z] OUTPUT: £
When letting it get to the orchestator, and then output what is shown using the StatusQueryURI
    "input": { "symbol": "�" }, "customStatus": null, "output": { "Input": { "symbol": "�" },
Unfortunately, I can't specify ASCII characters and then decode, as the symbol is part of another API request which requires that the pound symbol is shown as the symbol itself.
Providing Function Code:
HTTP TRIGGER
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
$FunctionName = $Request.Params.FunctionName
$InstanceId = Start-DurableOrchestration -FunctionName $FunctionName -Input $Request.Body
Write-Host "Started orchestration with ID = '$InstanceId'"
$Response = New-DurableOrchestrationCheckStatusResponse -Request $Request -InstanceId $InstanceId
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value $Response

ORCHESTRATION
param($Context)
return $Context;exit

JSON BODY
{
    "symbol" : "£"
}

To clarify, as soon as I read $Context, I can see the incorrect symbol.
DEBUG ATTEMPTS
I am trying to read what type of encoding is being used.
I am using the following function:
function Get-Encoding {
    param(
        [string]$InputString
    )

    $encodings = @(
        [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII,
        [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8,
        [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode,
        [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF32,
        [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF7,
        [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
    )

    foreach ($encoding in $encodings) {
        $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($InputString)
        $decodedString = $encoding.GetString($bytes)

        if ($decodedString -eq $InputString) {
            return $encoding.EncodingName
        }
    }

    return "Unknown"
}


When applying it to "$request.body" the encoding is : US-ASCII
When applying it to the "$Context" in Orchestrator, it is: Unicode

TEMP RESOLUTION
It appears that changing the powershell version from 7.2 to 7.4 as fixed the encoding issue.
Not sure how to resolve if you forced to use older versions.
If you want to change the local development version, you can modify your "local.settings.json" file and modify/add this variable:

"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION": "~7.4",



Please provide your function code.

Added the HTTP trigger and just the first part of the orchestration as I can see the symbol incorrectly straight away in the $context variable.

Yes, i too face similar issue when i am using 7.2 version of PowerShell Core with Azure Function. And I agree that after changing to PowerShell Core 7.4 it worked for me too :
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
$rithreq=$Request
$rithfunc = $rithreq.Params.FunctionName
$rithin = Start-DurableOrchestration -FunctionName $rithfunc -Input $rithreq.Body
$Response = New-DurableOrchestrationCheckStatusResponse -Request $rithreq -InstanceId $rithin
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value $Response

Output:


Not sure how to resolve if you forced to use older versions.

The 7.2 version will deprecate soon , so you will need to upgrade it any how:

